# My friend has stolen my IMEi number. Through this can he get my any data like whats app message, old history of Facebook login details?

Tags: imei

My friend has stolen my IMEi number. Through this can he get  my any personal data like whats app message, Calls records, old history of Facebook login details??

Comment: No, this is not possible. Likely duplicate of [What happens if an attacker steals my phone's IMEI number?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91751/what-happens-if-an-attacker-steals-my-phones-imei-number)

Comment: Your friend is trying to scare you, is not possible that scenario, check Steffen response for further information