# my friend stolen my imei number using this he can get my phone persona data?

Tags: malware, imei

He stolen my imei number  and even he knows my phone number. Using this can he get my any information such as call details, whats app messages and other phone activity???

Comment: Duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237907/my-enemy-stolen-my-imei-number-and-he-knows-my-phone-number-through-this-can-he and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237888/my-friend-has-stolen-my-imei-number-through-this-can-he-get-my-any-data-like-wh

Comment: You keep asking the same question over and over again. The answer is not going to change.