# What is the impact of someone accidentally getting my IMEI number from my Android phone?

Tags: passwords, phone, smartphone, risk, imei

I have a concern regarding how risky it is if someone knows or has the copy of my 2 IMEI numbers. As we all know, on Android phones, the IMEI are at the back cover of the phone like a sticker.

So, my question is, what if someone intentionally took my IMEI? What could he possibly do? I just want to know the risk factors. For example, could they use my IMEI to clone my phone or put my phone on the blacklist? Can an attacker do that by the use of IMEI numbers alone?

Comment: See [What happens if an attacker steals my phone's IMEI number?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91751/what-happens-if-an-attacker-steals-my-phones-imei-number)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's perceived as a duplicate, the links don't quiet lead you to a solid conclusion on the topic.

Basically this is the main attack vector you should be aware of, is called spoofing
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222016/spoofing-imei-numbers#222026

And the risk is present all of the time regardless of physical access to a device [What is the risk of leaking IMEI / IMSI numbers over a network](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49343/what-is-the-risk-of-leaking-imei-imsi-numbers-over-a-network)